# Add Internet Explorer 9 x64 tasks and frequent options in the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-9

Internet Explorer 9 x86 is the default on windows. As it is stated on microsoft site it can not be changed to default(If someone knows a way(not a workaround but a real solution like a registry tweak) to do that feel free to share).

If I pin it to the taskbar it works fine except of the right mouse click that isn't showing frequent and tasks as it shows on the x86 version.

Does someone know if it is available to do that and how?

Comment: But why?  Give me one good reason to use IE x64, because I can give a couple of good reasons not to.

Comment: I want to. :) I have a 64 bit OS and I want to run native apps. I have 64 bit flash and want to test it on IE9. more? 64 bit is the future? and just for the sake of debate... why not?